# How to get 0 value length in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How to get question `open eyes` `0 values length` in angularjs?

[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hs4YGbMryyIUXiagaXHL?p=preview)

- In my plunker I got the solution for (i) total no of questions (ii) total no of upvotes and (iii) Open eyes total sum of [value 1],  what we expecting is (iv) how to get `Open Eyes` 0 values `length`.
- How to get `Open Eyes` [0 values] `length`, please look at [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hs4YGbMryyIUXiagaXHL?p=preview) for reference  I don't know where I did the mistake
- If I used this `{{question.openeyes.length == '0'}` the answer I got `False`,
  Expecting answer would be : `2`

**My Html :-**

```
<p>Total no of questions :{{question.length}} </p>

<p>Total no of upvotes : {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'upvotes'}}</p>

<p>Total no of Open Eyes of [1 values] : {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'openeyes'}}</p>

<p class="color">Total no of Open Eyes of [0 value] : {{question.openeyes.length == '0'}}</p>
```

**My Data :-**

```
    $scope.question = [
   {
       "_id": "5936a70095e3a85804aae050",
       "user": {
           "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
           "displayName": "Table 1",
           "roles": ["admin"],
           "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/1f08308f43b0674d61a2cc5d95deb5ef",
           "email": "ms@e21designs.com",
           "categories": []
       },
       "__v": 1,
       "openeyers": ["sarawana@gmail.com"],
       "openeyes": 1,
       "upvoters": ["sarawana@gmail.com"],
       "upvotes": 1,
       "title": "what is cricket",
       "created": "2017-06-06T12:58:40.204Z"
},

   {
       "_id": "5936a70095e3a85804aae050",
       "user": {
           "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
           "displayName": "Table 1",
           "roles": ["admin"],
           "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/1f08308f43b0674d61a2cc5d95deb5ef",
           "email": "ms@e21designs.com",
           "categories": []
       },
       "__v": 1,
       "openeyers": [],
       "openeyes": 0,
       "upvoters": ["sarawana@gmail.com"],
       "upvotes": 1,
       "title": "who fan you are",
       "created": "2017-06-06T12:58:40.204Z"
},

   {
       "_id": "5936a70095e3a85804aae050",
       "user": {
           "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
           "displayName": "Table 1",
           "roles": ["admin"],
           "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/1f08308f43b0674d61a2cc5d95deb5ef",
           "email": "ms@e21designs.com",
           "categories": []
       },
       "__v": 1,
       "openeyers": [],
       "openeyes": 0,
       "upvoters": [  "ms@e21designs.com", "vp@gmail.com"],
       "upvotes": 2,
       "title": "best of the day",
       "created": "2017-06-06T12:58:40.204Z"
},
{
       "_id": "5936a70095e3a85804aae050",
       "user": {
           "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
           "displayName": "Table 1",
           "roles": ["admin"],
           "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/1f08308f43b0674d61a2cc5d95deb5ef",
           "email": "ms@e21designs.com",
           "categories": []
       },
       "__v": 1,
       "openeyers": ["ms@e21designs.com"],
       "openeyes": 1,
       "upvoters": ["ms@e21designs.com","vp@gmail.com", "ms@gmail.com"],
       "upvotes": 0,
       "title": "he is best",
       "created": "2017-06-06T12:58:40.204Z"
}]
```

- If any one knows of the solution please update `my plunker` as well to know the exact solution thanks

Comment: looks like you stuck in global and local varriables

Comment: question is an array. You are trying to reference which index?

Comment: @Vivz Thanks for your comment, I have tried your answer already it's not working so if possible update my plunker thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/7XedtmD6JlqpkgM3B7on?p=preview?

Comment: if you're trying to count questions where `openeyes` is 0, you can do this: http://plnkr.co/edit/DKHwgyb2KOuuRqPkO1J0?p=preview

Comment: @Kaddath Thanks for your answer it's working perfectly to us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a filter or call a function to get the length of `Open Eyes` [0 values] `length`. But using a filter is more preferred because the latter has performance issue.

**Method 1**: *Calling a function directly*

**JS**:

```
  $scope.openZero=function(q){
    var count =0;
    for(var i=0;i<q.length;i++){
      if(q[i].openeyes==0)
       count ++;         
    }
    return count;
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
<p class="color">Total no of Open Eyes of [0 value] : {{openZero(question)}}</p>
```

**Working Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/7XedtmD6JlqpkgM3B7on?p=preview

---

**Method 2** : *Using Filter*

**JS**

```
.filter('sumOfZero', function() {
            return function(data, key) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key)) return 0;
                var count = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (data[i].openeyes == 0) count++;
                }
                return count;
            }
```

**HTML**:

```
<p class="color">Total no of Open Eyes of [0 value] : {{resultValue | sumOfZeros:'openeyes'}}</p>
```

**Working Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/RjNWeqWEYuzbBdew8s7V?p=preview

Comment: Hi Vivz thanks for your valuable answer will check and update you asap...

Comment: Is there any possibility to count no of questions using instead of this `{{question.length}}` because it's not working in my project, it's working fine in plunker only, please update if you know the solution....

Comment: Why did you remove the answer?

Comment: by mistake, it happens cool and one more help if possible answer this question too: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976603/how-to-filter-ng-repeat-value-on-clicking-of-checkbox-field-in-angularjs/45977433#45977433 thanks..