# How to filter ng-repeat value on clicking of checkbox field in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

- Hi, all I want to filter `ng-repeat` value on clicking of check box field.
- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RSLeHLpVtFQcXXolK5QI?p=preview).
- On clicking of `Role block` checkbox it's should filter only the `roles` `value of block` elements.
- And On clicking of `My role` check box it's should filter only the `request_role` `value of Change agent data's or elements`

**My Html:-**

```
 <div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter: searchtable | filter: myrole">
            <small>
              <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <th>{{question.displayName}}</th>
                <th style="background: yellow;">,{{question.roles[0]}}</th>
                <th style="background: light;">,{{question.request_role[0]}}</th>

                </tbody>
                      </table>


              </small>
        </div>
```

**checkbox filter input :-**

```
<input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="searchtable.roles" value="block" ><span>Role block</span>

        <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-model="myrole.request_role" value="Change Agent" ><span>My role</span>
```

**My Data:-**

```
    $scope.users = [{
"_id": "59a6c7c96c2ce324124cc1d8",
"displayName": "blink foundation",
"provider": "local",
"location": "icf",
"username": "blink",
"dob": "1991-10-04T18:30:00.000Z",
"phone": 7299345250,
"religion": "Hindu",
"college_name": "Arignar Anna",
"__v": 2,
"created": "2017-08-30T14:12:25.397Z",
"roles": [
"block"
],
"request_role": [
"Change Agent"
],
"lastName": "foundation",
"firstName": "blink"
},
{
"_id": "598abfe4cce8ed582a2d8b32",
"displayName": "avinaash muthukumar",
"provider": "local",
"username": "avinaash muthu",
"__v": 0,
"created": "2017-08-09T07:55:16.511Z",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"request_role": [],
"firstName": "avinaash"
},
{
"_id": "5979a591c999e9302caece13",
"displayName": "Ajmal Afthab",
"provider": "local",
"location": "Urapakkam",
"username": "ajmal_afthab",
"dob": "1995-01-23T18:30:00.000Z",
"phone": 9500269131,
"religion": "Islam",
"__v": 1,
"roles": [
"kp"
],
"request_role": [],
"categories": [
"Religion & Culture",
"Moral Ethics",
"Social Psychology"
],
"lastName": "Afthab",
"firstName": "Ajmal"
},
{
"_id": "5978a2886d5b10ec321a2114",
"displayName": "happy selvam",
"provider": "local",
"username": "happy",
"__v": 0,
"created": "2017-07-26T14:09:12.730Z",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"request_role": [],
"categories": [],
"lastName": "selvam",
"firstName": "happy"
},
{
"_id": "58e73c5c9e2f3f1421e241be",
"displayName": "sarawana kumar",
"religion": "hindu",
"__v": 2,
"roles": [
"user"
],
"request_role": [],
"categories": [
"Religion & Culture",
"Social Psychology"
],
"lastName": "kumar",
"firstName": "sarawana"
},
{
"_id": "58d0fab62758cc482c295eba",
"displayName": "avinaash kumaran",
"provider": "local",
"username": "avinaash",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"request_role": [],
"categories": [],
"lastName": "kumaran",
"firstName": "avinaash"
},
    ]
```

*[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RSLeHLpVtFQcXXolK5QI?p=preview) what I exactly looking is on clicking check box the `ng-module` `value` should filter in the list of data's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more flexible solution will be to create a custom filter for your `ng-repeat`. The values from checkbox will be pushed into an array and filtering will be done based on these values. The filter is flexible as you can add more keys for filtering.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="searchtable.roles" value="block" ng-change="selectVal('block')"><span>Role block</span>
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="myrole.request_role" value="Change Agent" ng-change="selectVal('Change Agent')"><span>My role</span>
<div  ng-repeat="question in users| selectedTags:filterval">
```

**JS**:

```
$scope.filterval = [];
$scope.selectVal = function(val) {
    var index = $scope.filterval.indexOf(val);
    if (index > -1) $scope.filterval.splice(index, 1);
    else $scope.filterval.push(val);
}
```

**Custom Filter**:

```
app.filter('selectedTags', function() {
    return function(users, filterval) {
        if (filterval.length == 0) {
            return users;
        }
        var tempArr = [];
        angular.forEach(users, function(key, val) {
            tempArr.push(key);
        });
        return tempArr.filter(function(value) {
            //function to create filter for dynamic keys 
            function filterValue(parameter) {
                    for (var i in value[parameter]) {
                        if (filterval.indexOf(value[parameter][i]) != -1) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //pass any key you want in your object 
                //If you want your object to be filtered based on either of the key
            if (filterValue('roles') || filterValue('request_role')) {
                return true;
            } else return false;
            //If you want your object to be filtered based on both of the key              
            /*          if(filterValue('roles') && filterValue('request_role')) {
                          return true;
                        }
                        else
                          return false; */
        });
    };
})
```

**Working Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/XeFk0wn43IycRcOG0Arn?p=preview

Comment: The above answer will work with checkbox too as you can see from the demo.

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer this is also useful to me thanks, i give you upvote for this ....thanks.... and if possible please look at this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959394/how-to-set-end-date-as-a-current-or-todays-date-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="admin" ng-false-value=""  data-ng-model="filters.roles" ><span>Role block</span>   
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="Change Agent" ng-false-value=""  data-ng-model="filters.requestRoles" value="Change Agent" ><span>My role</span>

<div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter:{roles: filters.roles, request_role:filters.requestRoles}">
    <table border="0">
        <tbody>
            <th>{{question.displayName}}</th>
            <th style="background: yellow;">,{{question.roles[0]}}</th>
            <th style="background: light;">,{{question.request_role[0]}}</th>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

You have to declare `$scope.filters` and fill with default values in the `controller` to make it work better.

**Example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/JMiSiIWf7B78rDtxws4R?p=preview

Other solution is to create **Angular custom filter**.

Comment: @karol thanks for your valuable answer if possible please update my plunker as well to know the exact solution thanks

Comment: @karol thanks for your answer your code does not work in my portal, and I have found the answer I just changed type `checkbox` instead of `radio` it's working to me perfectly thanks....thank you so much for your help...